# How to reduce time when UITableView added Multiple NSURL UIImage on cell its UIBlocked

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, nsdata

I am trying to load an image form the internet into a cell.

When I'm using a single row then it's not taking much time, but when I have more then 5 rows then it is blocking UI. How can I solve this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In this method: I am using that Code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:upcImageLink];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
UIImage *imageObj = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[iconImgVw setImage:imageObj];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are currently, making sync calls to download the tableview cell image. Sync call takes time and your screen/UITableView becomes unresponsive to touch events. The technique to avoid this is called Lazy loading.

Use [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for lazy loading of tableview images. Usage is simple,

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also implement lazy loading of image on your own refering to the [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks ALl for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following code by replacing url:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 ), ^(void)
    {
        NSData * data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL] autorelease];
        UIImage * image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            if( image != nil )
            {
                [iconImgVw setImage:image];
            } else {
                //error
            }
        });
    });
```